# how to calculate Macauley modified duration in C#?

Tags: c#, excel-formula, duration

I want to implement this formula in C#.

MDURATION formula used in Excel

=MDURATION(43860,44233,0.2,0.19,2,3)

Is there a function or package for this?

Comment: What is formula for `MDURATION`? Have you tried any thing? show us your attempt

Comment: I found [this repo](https://github.com/onsense/universe/blob/78b3e673b6c2dfc3db48a5e7bc6f4efc5aa38307/src/main/java/io/onsense/universe/Financials.java#L2148-L2183) of Java implementations of Excel functions. It might be a starting point if you were to convert it to C#.

Comment: I won't add this as an answer since library recommendations are off-topic, but there seems to be a .NET NuGet package that might (I haven't checked) implement it: ExcelFinancialFunctions

Comment: Need to import this excel namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`
and then use `public double MDuration (object Arg1, object Arg2, object Arg3, object Arg4, object Arg5, object Arg6);`

Comment: Do you have any examples for this?

Comment: http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelFinancialFunctions/ there was a msdn for finiancial function but It has been relocate to an unknow place. It's an F# thing but it can be use in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NuGet Package`: [`ExcelFinancialFunctions`](http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelFinancialFunctions/):

```
using Excel.FinancialFunctions;


DateTime start = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);
double modifiedDuration = Financial.MDuration(
    start.AddDays(43860), 
    start.AddDays(44233), 
    0.2, 
    0.19,
    (Frequency)2, 
    (DayCountBasis)3);
```